# No Module named Pandas showing in server log but it has been already installed in server

Tags: python, pandas, odoo, odoo-10

I tried using Pandas for Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-173-generic x86_64) (Server).I want it for Python2.7.I tried `sudo pip install pandas` and `sudo apt-get install python-pandas`,`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas` it is getting installed,but when I try to use it in my Odoo's(ERP) Code,it is showing the error `No module named pandas`

After `sudo apt-get install python-pandas` it is showing :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pandas is already the newest version (0.17.1-3ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
```

I also tried:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.12.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 4.4.0-173-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.24.2
pytest: 2.8.7
pip: 20.0.2
setuptools: 44.0.0
Cython: None
numpy: 1.16.6
scipy: 0.17.0
pyarrow: None
xarray: None
IPython: None
sphinx: None
patsy: 0.4.1
dateutil: 2.8.1
pytz: 2019.3
blosc: None
bottleneck: None
tables: 3.2.2
numexpr: 2.4.3
feather: None
matplotlib: 1.5.1
openpyxl: 2.3.0
xlrd: 0.9.4
xlwt: 0.7.5
xlsxwriter: 0.7.3
lxml.etree: 3.5.0
bs4: 4.4.1
html5lib: 0.999
sqlalchemy: None
pymysql: None
psycopg2: 2.6.1 (dt dec mx pq3 ext lo64)
jinja2: 2.8
s3fs: None
fastparquet: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None
gcsfs: None
```

**Terminal**

```
2020-02-08 06:28:49,633 24303 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 10.0
2020-02-08 06:28:49,634 24303 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/techysuat.conf
2020-02-08 06:28:49,634 24303 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/opt/odoo10/techysuat/.local/share/Odoo/addons/10.0', u'/opt/odoo10/techysuat/addons', u'/opt/odoo10/techysuat/addons/xn_modules', u'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas', '/opt/odoo10/techysuat/odoo/addons']
2020-02-08 06:28:49,634 24303 INFO ? odoo: database: techysuat@default:default
2020-02-08 06:28:49,655 24303 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on netexodoo2:7030
2020-02-08 06:28:52,884 24303 INFO ? odoo.addons.report.models.report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
2020-02-08 06:28:53,349 24303 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2020-02-08 06:28:53,373 24303 INFO Techys_UAT odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2020-02-08 06:28:53,404 24303 INFO Techys_UAT odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.03s, 0 queries
2020-02-08 06:28:53,445 24303 INFO Techys_UAT odoo.modules.loading: loading 56 modules...
2020-02-08 06:28:53,727 24303 CRITICAL Techys_UAT odoo.modules.module: Couldn't load module xn_registration_form
2020-02-08 06:28:53,727 24303 CRITICAL Techys_UAT odoo.modules.module: No module named pandas
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** :Now Server for this instance has been changed and I think now packages has been installed in a virtual env.
I tried installing pandas in virtual env,but is showing permission issues.
Ways Tried:

```
(venv) abc@erp:/opt/odoo10/abcuat/venv/bin$ pip install pandas
```

Error :

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/odoo10/techyslive/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I tried using : `pip install pandas --user`
Then this error :

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I also repeated these same steps with `pip2.7 install pandas`,`pip2 install pandas` etc.
Please help

Comment: Does `pip2.7 install pandas` solve the issue?

Comment: you should not install anything on the system python and use a virtual environment for your projects.Also, in 2020 use python3 unless there's a really good reason why you want to use and unsupported, old python for which libraries like pandas are no longer updated

Comment: @576i Currently I am using python3 bro.Had done some work for an old project running in python2 and actually server is setuped by other person and he haven't created a virtual environment.Thanks bro.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Please check the edits.

Comment: @576i Please check the edits.

Comment: either use `sudo` or `chmod 777 [path where permission is denied]`

Comment: @SayandipDutta While using sudo the package will be installed in system's python right ?
I will try using chmod 777

Comment: @SayandipDutta Thanks a lot bro.. chmod method worked.
Please try this question also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162445/more-space-is-coming-between-header-and-page1-but-from-page2-it-is-correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 'pip', use 'pip2' and run command.

You may try with following:

```
sudo pip2 install pandas
```

Or

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

**EDIT:**

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/odoo10/techyslive/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*
```

Comment: You got `Permission denied` means User doesn't have permission to write/install on that folder. You have two options. 1) Run command with `sudo` user, 2) Give read/write/create permission to current User.

Comment: 1)While using `sudo` the package will be installed in system's python right ?
2)How to give this permission for virtual env... 
I have less experience working in server.
Thanks

Comment: try with this command: `sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/odoo10/techyslive/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*`

Comment: This worked bro.. `sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/odoo10/techyslive/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*`
I replaced * with every coming permission issue and finally the package got installed..
Please edit your answer and I will accept it..
Thanks a lot..
Thanks for @SayandipDutta also.He also gave the similar answer

Comment: Please try this question also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162445/more-space-is-coming-between-header-and-page1-but-from-page2-it-is-correct