# More space is coming between Header and Page1 but from page2 it is correct

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I tried creating a QWEB report with custom Paper Format but more space is coming between Header and Page1 but from page2 it is correct.I tried adjusting `Margin Top` and `Header Spacing`.
Thanks in Advance
[image: Please Refer This Image]

**Page Format**

```
<record id="paper_xn_so_preprint" model="report.paperformat">
    <field name="name">Sale Order PrePrint</field>
    <field name="default" eval="True"/>
    <field name="format">custom</field> 
    <field name="page_height">148</field>
    <field name="page_width">210</field>
    <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
    <field name="margin_top">50</field>
    <field name="margin_bottom">14</field>
    <field name="margin_left">0</field>
    <field name="margin_right">0</field>
    <field name="header_line" eval="False"/>
    <field name="header_spacing">20</field>
    <field name="dpi">90</field>
</record>
```

**Template Sample**

```
<template id="xn_saleorder_preprint">
    <!-- <t t-call="report.html_container"> -->
    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="row col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Customer
                    ID
                    Mobile
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Sale Order
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
                    Order Date
                    Delivery Date
                    SO Number
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            Page Contents
        </div>
    </t>
</template>
```

**EDIT**

I think the problem is caused by the table.But was not able to figure where the problem is.

**CODE**

```
<div class="page">
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <th>Sl No.</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th">Unit Price</th>
            <th>Taxes</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <t t-set="sl_no" t-value="0"/>
            <tr t-foreach="o.order_line" t-as="line">
                <t t-set="sl_no" t-value="sl_no+1"/>
                <td><span t-esc="sl_no"/></td><br/>
                <td><span t-field="line.xn_order_customer_name"/></td>
                <td><span t-field="line.product_id.name"/></td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <t t-if = "float(line.product_uom_qty.is_integer())">
                        <span t-esc = "int(line.product_uom_qty)" />
                    </t>
                    <t t-if = "not float(line.product_uom_qty.is_integer())" >
                        <span t-field = "line.product_uom_qty" />
                    </t>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right"><span t-field="line.price_unit"/></td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <t t-set="vat_amount" t-value="0"/>
                    <t t-foreach="line.tax_id" t-as="x">
                        <t t-set="vat_amount" t-value="vat_amount+(line.price_subtotal*x.amount/100)"/>
                    </t>
                    <span t-esc="vat_amount" t-options="{'widget': 'float', 'precision': 2}"/>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right"><span t-field="line.xn_discount_amt" t-options="{'widget': 'float', 'precision': 2}"/></td>
                <td class="text-right"><span t-field="line.price_subtotal"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with following:

```
<field name="margin_top">10</field>
```

**EDIT:**

You may try `web.html_container` and `web.external_layout` template.

```
<template id="template_xn_saleorder_preprint">
    <t t-call="web.external_layout">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="row col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Customer
                    ID
                    Mobile
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    Sale Order
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
                    Order Date
                    Delivery Date
                    SO Number
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            Page Contents
        </div>
    </t>
</template>


<template id="xn_saleorder_preprint">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="template_xn_saleorder_preprint"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

**EDIT:**

It is because of this code:
`<td><span t-esc="sl_no"/></td><br/>`

Comment: Hi..!! Tried this.. Header Portion is partially cut-off while using this.

Comment: @vbt I have edited my answer. You may try that one.

Comment: Tried this with `report.` instead of `web.` as it is `odoo10` But the result is still the same.

Comment: how about to decrease header spacing?

Comment: Bro.. I think it is because of the table.. Will update the code soon.. First tried putting the whole code but stack overflow was not allowing coz of the low explaination.

Comment: Opps. Please make sure you have related code in your question. Otherwise It will be hard to understand and provide solution. So we can avoid waste time.

Comment: I tried putting a small version earlier but because of the small expaination, I was not able to post it.So finally had to settle with very low amount of code.
And initially I thought the problem is with Page Format.
Sorry for wasting your time.
Please check on the edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207642/discussion-between-vbt-and-bhavesh-odedra).